# context menu not fired after click

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, contextmenu

i using d3 version 5 and react.js and d3-context-menu plugin. i showing an external svg with object tag and i want add a context menu but after right click d3-context-menu not fired.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import contextMenuFactory from 'd3-context-menu';
.
.
.   
 let svg = document.querySelector('#svgobject');
      let svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;
      svg.onload = () => {
        let g = d3.select(svgDoc);
        var menu = [
          {
            title: 'Item #1',
            action: function(d, i) {
              console.log('Item #1 clicked!');
              console.log('The data for this circle is: ' + d);
            },
            disabled: false, // optional, defaults to false
          },
          {
            title: 'Item #2',
            action: function(d, i) {
              console.log('You have clicked the second item!');
              console.log('The data for this circle is: ' + d);
            },
          },
        ];
        g.selectAll('g').on('contextmenu', contextMenuFactory(menu));
      };
```